# Dimensions of charge in natural units

Tags: homework-and-exercises, units, dimensional-analysis, physical-constants, absolute-units

The natural units

$$G = c = \hbar = k_{B} = 1$$

set fundamental constants of gravity, relativity, quantum physics, and statistical physics to simple numbers.

However, surprisingly, the natural units imply that charge has the dimensions of length$^{-1}$.

How does this follow?

For reference, see the text in [3] of page 6 of the [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1705.06287).

Comment: In the Standard Model, all three of the coupling constants for the U(1), SU(2) and SU(3) groups are dimensionless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The note uses Planck units to set the dimension of charge equal to the dimension of mass.

However, it does not state *explicitly* that this is true in Planck units. It only mentions that

$$G = c = \hbar = k_{B} = 1.$$

In Planck units, we also have

$$\frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_{0}} = 1.$$

The dimension of $1/4\pi\epsilon_{0}$ is $L^{3}MT^{-2}Q^{-2}$. Therefore, we find that $Q = M$ in Planck units.

Comment: well, in Planck units, every physical quantity is dimensionless.  not just $Q$ and $M$.